# Regex email code not matching. C# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, email-validation

I am new to c# and Ive come across something I can't fix.

## situation

I am creating a windows form application using visual studio 2010 which has the option to validate an email address. I looked at tutorials on using `RegularExpression`s and have came to this. I feel I'm missing something because every time I validate, it only sends the `MessageBox.Show("Email invalid");` to the user.

## code

```
private void validateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex email = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1-20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1-20}.[a-zA-Z]{2-3}$");

    if (!email.IsMatch(emailTxt.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Email invalid");
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Email Valid");
}
```

Comment: having the text you are tryint to validate would help

Comment: What is the email address that you're entering that it fails on?  Your regex has couple of issues.  One is that `.` is a special character that means "any character"; you're using it as literal and should be escaped like `\.` (but that would not cause failure.  Second issue that I see is that it will not handle addresses like `one@two.three.com`.  But give us your input so we can help better.

Comment: Obligatory link for anyone who's trying to [use a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/1336590).

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would never use an `Exception` to direct program logic like this, but when validating emails I've found using built-in .NET functionality to be more reliable and readable than trying to [use Regex to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

```
using (var mm = new MailMessage())
{
    try
    {
        mm.To.Add(emailTxt.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Email Valid");

        ... rest of your code to send the email
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Email Invalid");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, to just test the address:

```
try
{
    var mail = new MailAddress(emailTxt.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Email Valid");
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Email Invalid");
}
```

This class is not perfect, and you can find posts showing it doesn't catch every edge case.

But when [this is the alternative](http://fightingforalostcause.net/content/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php), I think I'd rather stick with the above and take my chances.

Answer (score 0):

`.` is a special character, use

```
Regex email = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1-20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1-20}\.[a-zA-Z]{2-3}$");
```

please note I added a `'@'` in front of the string to avoid escaping the `'\'`

Comment: That likely isn't the root cause of the issue (we don't have OP's input data to know for sure), since `.` special character will actually match `.` literal and wouldn't cause failure.

Answer (score 0):

You have two syntax errors in your regex:

`.` stands for a random sign, so it must be escaped with a backslash: `\.` .

`{1-20}` musst be written with comma: `{1,20}`.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}
```

works.

if you use C# you have to bring a `@` before the first `"` to say it that it should not use backslashes in the string to escape. It should do this when searching for regex.

```
@"[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3} "
```

Comment: thanks, i updated my code with this and it works! :)